# Strongly typed deep equal assertion with TypeScript and Chai

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have a TypeScript function that returns a type `Foo`:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
}

function getFoo(): Foo {
  return {
    bar: 'hello',
    baz: 'world',
  };
}

// Chai Assertion
it('Should return a Foo', () => {
  expect(getFoo()).to.deep.equal({
    bar: 'hello',
    baz: 'world',
  });
})
```

When I change the `Foo` interface, my `getFoo()` function produces a TypeScript error:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: number;  // change these to numbers instead
  baz: number;
}

function getFoo(): Foo {
  // Compile time error! Numbers aren't strings!
  return {
    bar: 'hello',
    baz: 'world',
  };
}
```

However, my Mocha test does not trigger a compile time error!

Is there a type-safe way of doing `expect().to.deep.equal()`? Something like:

```
// Strawman for how I'd like to do type-safety for deep equality assertions,
// though this generic signature still seems unnecessary?
expect<Foo>(getFoo()).to.deep.equal({
  bar: 'hello',
  baz: 'world',
});
```

Comment: Mocka/Assertion is actually working as expected, you are asserting your return is what you expected. If you want to test types you'll need to assert on that like this
https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a. I would leave the types to typescript tho. that is what you got it there for

Comment: can you try `expect<Foo>(getFoo()).to.have.interface(Foo)`? p.s. but for this you need the module `chai-interface`

Comment: @quirimmo Unfortunately, chai `expect` does not expect any type arguments, so the generic signature is incorrect.

Comment: sorry I usually use `should`, it gives me more an idea of BDD approach, btw the package I am saying for interfaces is here: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-interface/

Comment: No worries, this should be doable without a chai plugin if the `expect` type signature  expressed the coupling between the actual and expected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a type-safe way of doing expect().to.deep.equal()

Not in the type definitions of `equal` which are intentionally `any` as it is designed for *runtime* checking.

However easy to do externally:

```
const expected: Foo = {
  bar: 'hello',
  baz: 'world',
};
expect(getFoo()).to.deep.equal(expected);
```

Comment: I would even create a variable before returning it in the getFoo() function to avoid the return type on the method. Then your test and your function under test both create a variable :)